# Create an "App hub" in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to create an Application hub in Windows Phone 8? (similar to music+videos app or the marketplace)

Essentially, the idea is to have 2 apps, say "Foo" and "Bar". I would like a third app, say "Fubar", which when launched contains the apps "Foo" and "Bar" as links to be launched (so "Fubar" becomes like a container app for the other two)

I am trying to experiment with some security authorization stuff, and both "Foo" and "Bar" need to check for the same security token. The idea is that the user will login to "Fubar" and get the token, which can then be used by both "Foo" and "Bar" rather than to pass the token between the apps.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: There is a simple way to launch other apps from your app using URIs, but basically what I need is "Fubar" presents a list of 2 apps, "Foo" and "bar", the user clicks on any of those and the app gets launched. No URI information needs to be strictly exchanged, but I guess I can piggyback on this mechanism. Not sure though how to make a list of apps in another app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply have one app launch another in windows phone due to security limitations, all app to app communication must be moderated by the OS and can be done through file or URI associations.

Check these links to learn more about app-to-app communication:

- [Channel 9: App to App Communication in Windows Phone 8](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-10-App-to-App-Communication-in-Windows-Phone-8)
- [Build 2012: App to App Communication](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-044)

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm using URI associations for now, hopefully that should be enough.